# Laravel запрос в бд выполняется очень долго

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Есть запрос:

```
        $items = DB::table('items_be')->select(
            '*',
            DB::raw('(select name from mf where id = items_be.mf_id limit 1) as mf_name'),
            DB::raw('(select logo from mf where id = items_be.mf_id limit 1) as mf_logo'),
            DB::raw('(select SUM(quant) from items_en where be_id = items_be.id AND block= 0 AND deleted= 0) as in_en'),
            DB::raw('(select SUM(quant) from items_ei where be_id = items_be.id AND block= 0 AND deleted= 0) as in_ei')
        )->where([
            'obj_id' => $id
        ])->get();
```

Выполнение этого запроса длится 22-25 секунд, но если его выполнить в phpmyadmin напрямую, то он выполнится за 1-2 секунды.

Если я уберу вложенные запросы SELECT SUM(quant), то все будет ок.

Почему такая разница в скорости и как можно решить эту проблему? Спасибо!

**UPDATE:**

Так же пробовал такой вариант, тоже самое.

```
         $items = DB::select(DB::raw("
            select *,
            (select name from mf where id = items_be.mf_id limit 1) as mf_name, 
            (select logo from mf where id = items_be.mf_id limit 1) as mf_logo, 
            (select SUM(quant) from items_en where be_id = items_be.id AND block= 0 AND deleted= 0) as in_en, 
            (select SUM(quant) from items_ei where be_id = items_be.id AND block= 0 AND deleted= 0) as in_ei
            from items_be 
            where items_be.obj_id = $id
        "));
```

Comment: Перепишите ВЕСЬ запрос в один `DB::raw`.

Comment: Переписал в 1 DB::raw, не помогло. Выполняется так же долго.

Comment: *Переписал в 1 DB::raw* Добавьте в текст вопроса в форме "UPDATE:", как именно Вы это сделали... должно быть `$items = DB::raw('текст запроса')->get();`, в крайнем случае `$items = DB::raw('текст запроса')->where(['obj_id' => $id])->get();`.